# python, trouble with calling functions from a module

Tags: python, import, module

I imported a module as below:

```
filename = "email"
mymodule = __import__('actions.'+filename)
```

the problem I have with this is, that the file is immediatly executing, and I would much rather execute a specific function from the file (that way I can send variables through it).

I am basically working with plugins, so it works.

**Edit**:
for the time being, I am not concerned with whether or not the script executes when I add the line below:

```
mymodule = __import__('actions.'+filename)
```

but what I would like to work is when I  add the line below, I would like the function to execute. But instead I get an error that the module dosn't have that function even though it exisits in the script.

```
mymodule.dosomething(n)
```

**Edit**:
I personally don't think that the function has anything to do with it but here is one python files that I am trying to open.

```
import webbrowser
def OpenEmail():
    handle = webbrowser.get()
    handle.open('http://gmail.google.com')
OpenEmail()
print "Your email has been opened"
```

Comment: Please add some more code relevant to the function that doesn't work.

Comment: I personally dont think the function has anything to do with it. I have tried it with many different functions and it did not work. Here is the error---- AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OpenEmail'

Answer (score 2):

The functions don't exist unless the module executes. You can't have it both ways. Perhaps you need to add a [main stanza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to the module.

Comment: ok, so I think I know what to do with a main stanza. Please check the edit (if you don't see it I will add it in a second) in the main post, just bceause I can not format it correctly in a comment

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you get the `actions` module returned. Try this:

```
mymodule = __import__('actions.'+filename)
for submodule in filename.split('.'):
    mymodule = getattr(mymodule, submodule)
```

This happens when you try importing a submodule, i.e. `module.something.somethingelse`, you get `module` returned.

Comment: actions is a folder, when I tried using the "/" character I got syntax error problems.

Comment: @user1270285 Yes, I'm aware it is a folder. That's how Python modules work. `/` denotes division. Have you tried whether it works?

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OpenEmail'

Comment: @user1270285: Is `OpenMail` the name of your package, or just the name of a function? Can you update the post with your folder/file structure and what `filename` is when you invoke the code?